# Gameobject that follow a player in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm new at unity and I try to make a gameobject follow my player but the result is that my game object goes to the opposite direction.

Here is my code

```
public class Ennemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform _transform;
    private Transform _target;
    
   /* public Transform Target
    {
        get => _target;
        set => _target = value;
    }
*/
    private void Start()
    {
        _transform = transform;
        _target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        _transform.Translate(_target.position * (1f * Time.deltaTime), Space.Self);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try negating `_target.position`, by doing `-_target.position`.

Also, multiplying `Time.deltaTime` by 1 will do nothing to deltaTime, so unless you plan on changing that you can omit the `1f *`.

Comment: Nice it works but when my player goes too far of my ennemy then it goes back to the wrong direction ? So i don't understand why ?

Comment: Its because transform.Translate expects a direction from the object you call it on. A point, like the position of an object is a direction from the world origin.

If you want to create a direction from the two objects, you'll need to subtract the vectors. The other answer here actually covers that, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Translate(...) moves the object by the vector passed into it.
Thus you have to calculate the direction to the player

```
Vector3 dir = (_target.position - _transform.position).normalized;
_transform.Translate(dir * Time.deltaTime);
```